# How do I get the elements in an Angular component and hide/show them?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to build a wizard component in Angular. In order to make a progress bar and hide/show steps I want to be able to figure out the number of steps in the wizard by counting the number of "step" templates inside it. I just learnt about the concept of `ContentChildren` which gives me the `elementRef` objects but I don't know how do I go from there:

`wizard.component.ts`

```
import { ... } from '@angular/core

export class WizardComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

    @ContentChildren('step') steps: QueryList<any>;

}

ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.steps.forEach(step => console.log(step));

}
```

`wizard.component.html`

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

`app.component.html`

```
<app-wizard>
    <div #step> First Step Screen </div>
    <div #step> Second Step Screen </div>
</app-wizard>
```

Comment: I don't see the show/hide part in the body of the question.

Comment: Say private currentStep = 0. And have an object like activeScreen. activeScreen = this.wizardStepElements[this.currentStep]. Would work, right?